# paw: copy response field into environment

Tags: javascript, response, paw

Using Paw, I am accessing an endpoint that I use to make an authentication request. The response is returned via JSON and contains a sessionId, which I need to place into my environment as a variable (SESSION_ID). This environment variable is then used in the Authorization header of all requests sent back to the server.

Is there a way to script the extraction of the sessionId value from the authentication response and place the value into the environment variable, without having to perform a copy and paste each time I authenticate?

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. The right way of achieving this in Paw is in a declarative manner. Instead of extracting from the response on each call, you set the environment variable's value to point to a specific field within this JSON response.

For that, the [Response Parsed Body Dynamic Value](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Response_Parsed_Body_Dynamic_Value) will be helpful.

1. On the JSON or Form URL-Encoded response, right click on a field and pick "Copy as Response Body Dynamic Value":

[image: Copy a Response Body Dynamic Value from a Response Field in Paw]

2. Paste it on your environments, or in any field you want:

[image: Use a response field anywhere in Paw]

You can read the [documentation about this](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Response_Parsed_Body_Dynamic_Value).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: But if it's possible to push the token to only active environment?
I have 3 environments and once I receive token, it's changing the token value for all 3 environments, even not active(((